# Why does slice assignment in dataframes consider indices?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Coming from numpy, I would expect this snippet

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10))

df1[4:6] = df2[5:7]

print(df1)
```

to yield something along the lines of

```
          0
0  0.851412
1  0.533122
2  0.244325
3  0.242295
4  5.000000
5  6.000000
6  0.036066
7  0.350092
8  0.400461
9  0.744239
```

Instead, I get

```
          0
0  0.210079
1  0.603919
2  0.541231
3  0.693830
4       NaN
5  5.000000
6  0.742590
7  0.318744
8  0.954216
9  0.641225
```

Obviously, pandas takes into account the indices of `df1` and `df2` when performing the assignment. I know that I can achieve my desired result using

```
df1[4:6] = df2[5:7].values
```

but I can't figure out for the life of me why checking the indices of two potentially unrelated dataframes would make sense. I also browsed the documentation but could not find anything related. Is my mental model of a dataframe wrong? My pandas version is 0.18.

Comment: If the index was something meaningful (for instance a user) and the second dataframe contained information on users that you wanted to add to the first, then it would make sense.

Comment: I guess that when they designed this they thought that when you are assign something from one dataframe to another dataframe, that they *are* probably related and that it makes sense to compare the indices.
Here you can find more about how to join/merge dataframes, but I assume you read this already: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Comment: PS. I would indeed say that your mental model of a dataframe is wrong :) This index-based logic was for me the hardest part when I started using pandas.

Comment: Good points, I can now see that `df1[4:6] = df2` can make sense regardless of the number of rows in df2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `index` is what makes a `pandas` `dataframe` something more than a `numpy` `ndarray`.  You may have tripped over a seemingly minor inconvenience, but that same characteristic allows for many powerful operations that cannot be accomplished with `numpy` alone.